# How to auto save Nunit tests result in html file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using Nunit extension with Selenium tests in Visual Studio 2012.
Nunit has an option to save results in txt, xml or html files.
But what I want to do is to *automatically* save results in html after every test complited.

Comment: Where does NUnit have the option to save as HTML or TXT?  All I see in the console and GUI runner is an XML output.

Comment: Nunit extension in Visual Studio 2012. It has such options. Not desktop program.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about v0.96 of the test adapter, I don't believe it has such an option. You get much more control over the output formatting if you run `nunit-console` (perhaps as a post-build step in your project) and then apply some sort of XSLT to the output XML which it generates. NUnit v3 promises to have even more control, but I don't believe even that will have HTML output as an option directly from the Visual Studio test adapter.

Comment: Well, I have this in my VS2012, isn't it Nunit vor Visual Studio?http://oi58.tinypic.com/313p0m9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Updated Approach :
Save below lines as a batch file and call this at the end of TearDown method in your test case or test suite. The batch file will take 3 parameters, path to testresult.xml generated by nUnit, path where this xml has to be copied (make sure folder exists), path to output html file to be generated.

Batch file will wait until xml is generated from nUnit , then converts it.
I'm using NUnit2Report.Console for converting xml to html. You can get it from Nuget.

@ECHO Waiting for the file %1 to be generated.

:CheckForFile
@ECHO THIS WINDOW WILL BE CLOSED AUTOMATICALLY. DO NOT CLOSE IT.
if exist %1 goto FileExists
ping -n 10 localhost >NUL
goto :CheckForFile

:FileExists
copy %1 %2
"NUnit2Report.Console.Runner.1.0.0.0\NUnit2Report.Console.exe" --fileset=%2 --out %3

Comment: can you show me example %1 what parameter will used?